# AWS - Keeping AMIs updated

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, autoscaling, cloud-init

Let's say I've created an AMI from one of my EC2 instances. Now, I can add this manually to then LB or let the AutoScaling group to do it for me (based on the conditions I've provided). Up to this point everything is fine.

Now, let's say my developers have added a new functionality and I pull the new code on the existing instances. Note that the AMI is not updated at this point and still has the old code. My question is about how I should handle this situation so that when the autoscaling group creates a new instance from my AMI it'll be with the latest code.

Two ways come into my mind, please let me know if you have any other solutions:

a) keep AMIs updated all the time; meaning that whenever there's a pull-request, the old AMI should be removed (deleted) and replaced with the new one.

b) have a start-up script (cloud-init) on AMIs that will pull the latest code from repository on initial launch. (by storing the repository credentials on the instance and pulling the code directly from git)

Which one of these methods are better? and if both are not good, then what's the best practice to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that anything (almost) can be automated using the AWS using the API; it would again fall down to the specific use case at hand.

At the outset, people would recommend having a base AMI with necessary packages installed and configured and have init script which would download the the source code is always the latest. The very important factor which needs to be counted here is the time taken to checkout or pull the code and configure the instance and make it ready to put to work. If that time period is very big - then it would be a bad idea to use that strategy for auto-scaling. As the warm up time combined with auto-scaling & cloud watch's statistics would result in a different reality [may be / may be not - but the probability is not zero]. This is when you might consider baking a new AMI frequently. This would enable you to minimize the time taken for the instance to prepare themselves for the war against the traffic.

I would recommend measuring and seeing which every is convenient and cost effective. It costs real money to pull down the down the instance and relaunch using the AMI; however thats the tradeoff you need to make.

While, I have answered little open ended; coz. the question is also little.

People have started using Chef, Ansible, Puppet which performs configuration management. These tools add a different level of automation altogether; you want to explore that option as well. A similar approach is using the Docker or other containers.

Answer (score 1):

> a) keep AMIs updated all the time; meaning that whenever there's a
>   pull-request, the old AMI should be removed (deleted) and replaced
>   with the new one.

You shouldn't store your source code in the AMI. That introduces a maintenance nightmare and issues with autoscaling as you have identified.

> b) have a start-up script (cloud-init) on AMIs that will pull the
>   latest code from repository on initial launch. (by storing the
>   repository credentials on the instance and pulling the code directly
>   from git)
>
> Which one of these methods are better? and if both are not good, then
>   what's the best practice to achieve this goal?

Your second item, downloading the source on server startup, is the correct way to go about this.

Other options would be the use of Amazon CodeDeploy or some other deployment service to deploy updates. A deployment service could also be used to deploy updates to existing instances while allowing new instances to download the latest code automatically at startup.